I try to make the navigation bar to use the full column but the grid column applied in my code css do not work
Why is the grid-column does not work is my css.
my webpage have 3 column as define in the container class.
container{
display: grid;
grid-template-column: repeat(3 , 1fr)
}

but i want for the navigation bar to use the full width to occupied the full column
navigation ul{
grid-column: 1 / -1;
display: flex,
justify-content: space-evenly;
}

unfortunatly it is not working.
Here how it is displaying instead of occupying the full width, the full column. check the yellow line how it is blank the navigation bar should have be fully used by (Home, about us,items, agents, contact) but it is just on a corner.

Please check up my code , a proper explanation ad correction would be highly appreciate.
1.HTML part
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navigationbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Items</li>
                    <li>agents</li>
                    <li>contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>


CSS part

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3 , 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}



.navigationbar ul{
 grid-column: 1 / -1;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}



Please post code as text, not images of text.  And you provide any details as to what "does not work" means?

PLease provide all code as text, or better still a [MCVE]

The problem in your code is that you have too many nested elements, and are then getting confused about which styles to apply to which elements. To make the navigation bar span the three grid columns, you need to apply grid-column style to the .navigationbar itself, as the direct descendant of your container grid, not to the ul element inside it.
By simplifying your HTML structure you will find the styling becomes easier.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.container>* {
  background: pink;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.d1, .d2, .d3 {
  height: 100px;
}
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>About us</a>
        <a>Items</a>
        <a>agents</a>
        <a>contact</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="d1"></div>
    <div class="d2"></div>
    <div class="d3"></div>
</div>    



